# "Expecting a type here because of type ascription"

Tags: rust

I have some code that is attempting to read in a list of strings into struct values. With the code below, I am attempting to just print the lines from the `input_file` vector from inside `POLIR::generate_config()`. I am getting the error:

```
error: expected type, found `{`
 --> src/main.rs:5:27
  |
5 |         for line in args: {
  |                           ^ expecting a type here because of type ascription
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
struct POLIR {}

impl POLIR {
    fn generate_config(&self, args: Vec<String>) {
        for line in args: {
            println!{"{}", line};
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    //other program stuff
    let input_file = lines_from_file(input_file);

    let system = POLIR {};

    POLIR::generate_config(&system, input_file);
}
```

Comment: Re-read the error. `"did you mean to use ';' here?"`.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead realized I had a type in the code block I posted.

Comment: Though I still get the same error.

Comment: I'll point you to [the book which has examples on using `for...loop`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-05-control-flow.html#repetition-with-loops) for you to review. There is a very obvious syntactical error in your code.

Comment: Ah, I see it. Thank you for your help. @SimonWhitehead

Comment: Too much python?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields and `UpperCamelCase` for types. Use `Polir` instead, please.

Answer (score 2):

This error was solved by removing the colon from `POLIR::generate_config()`:

```
fn generate_config(&self, args: Vec<String>) {
    for line in args {
        println!{"{}", line};
    }
}
```